Do not get SIGTERM with node --watch mode
OS: Windows 11
node --version: v21.7.3 (also tested with other versions, 18.20.3)
index.js:
// to create the event loop
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('hello');
}, 2500);

console.log('hi!');

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('got SIGTERM');
  clearInterval(timer);
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('got SIGINT');
  clearInterval(timer);
});

Running node --watch --watch-preserve-output index.js
Then I update the file and expect to see got SIGTERM output, but I don't get it.
Restarting 'test-node.js'
updated hi! 

The thing is that it works on https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-qv37ky?file=index.js
Restarting 'index.js'
got SIGTERM
updated hi!

I just don't understand why it doesn't handle the signal on my workstation? What can be the reason for this behaviour?
